# Why is my friends' suggestion not visible?

Tags: facebook, friend-list

I went to my friend's profile, and click the "gear" button and selected "suggest friends". In the popup that came, I choose the friends I thought to be mutual friends, and it shows "friend suggestion sent". But, the weird thing is that, my friend for whom I did the whole thing did not receive any of my friend suggestions. 
What is wrong ?